# Are previously made HTTP Requests accessible via Javascript

Tags: javascript, http, security, browser, xss

Are the responses/payloads of previously made HTTP requests accessible programmatically via Javascript?

I’d like know, if in the same way hackers can use XSS to access cookies/localStorage stores in the browser, can they access data from previously made HTTP requests (since the browser DevTools has the previous requests listed and visible in the network tab).

Comment: No, they can't. XSS can override the global `fetch` function and the global `XMLHttpRequest` constructor, however, which would allow a log of sorts to be created

Answer (score 1):

They are only accessible if code runs before or during the request that programatically saves the response. For example, one could overwrite `window.fetch` and save (but pass through) all requests and responses, or do the same for XMLHttpRequest, or save the result of a request normally inside a `.then` or in an `onload` handler.

Devtools does have access to prior requests, but devtools has access to *many* things that can't be done via JavaScript - this is one of them.

Comment: From my perspective devtools also don't have access to prior made requests. While devtools is active it records requests and responses but if you open devtools the network tab is empty, thus no prior request is shown (at least devtools works this way in browsers I use).